# Hide everything except Custom Overlay in Android Google Maps Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, custom-overlay

I currently have an overlay set up in my app for google maps on a google maps activity.

The image lines up perfectly, but when you leave the area of the overlay you see the normal google maps view.

I want to hide everything except Custom Overlay, how can I go about doing that?

In order to prevent a user from zooming out from where I have the camera zoomed in and losing the custom overlay, can I lock the user to only be within certain gps coordinates?  (The area covered by the custom overlay)

Comment: You could use framelayout as root with the overlay as a transparent layout covering the whole map. Finally capture / block all touch events on the overlay.

Comment: I don't want want to lock zooming in, or zooming out after zooming in, but I want to lock the zoom to be a max of X

Comment: That I believe you can handle through the options avaliable in the GoogleMap object

Comment: It looks like the answer is creating another overlay like I did, and like you said making it a huge size when putting it in:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is creating another overlay like I did, and like cYrixmorten said making it a huge size when putting it in.  I used 10,000:

```
GroundOverlayOptions audubonTrailMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.trailmapimage))
            .position(schlitzAudubon, 10000f, 10000f);

mMap.addGroundOverlay(audubonTrailMap);
```